# Variable visibility in function prototype JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, visibility

I have a source js file where I have this code. I need to manage the `est_bandwidth` array in the script but even if I'm sure of the correct creation I can't see globally. Why? How can I see the array also outside of the function?

```
var maxBandwidth = 8 * 1024 * 1024;        // 8 Mbps
var est_bandwidth = new Array();
function bandwidth(initial_bps, weight_f, weight_s){

    this.bps = initial_bps;
    this.weight_f = weight_f;
    this.weight_s = weight_s;

}

bandwidth.prototype.calcWeightedBandwidth = function(_bps) {
    this.bps = parseInt(((this.weight_f * this.bps) + (this.weight_s * _bps)) / 2) * 0.9;
    if (this.bps > maxBandwidth && maxBandwidth > 0) this.bps = maxBandwidth;
    est_bandwidth.push(this.bps / 1024);
    return this.bps;
}
```

The result when I try to access `est_bandwidth` is an empty array. If I modify after the declaration with this:

```
est_bandwidth[0] = 1;
est_bandwidth[1] = 2;
```

I get, as result in my console, [1,2]. I can see `est_bandwidth` but only outside the function and I don't know why.

Here it is the complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/4DY5C/1. You must refer to `banda_stimata` instead of `est_bandwidth`. The code is in bandwidth.js among the sources.

Comment: How and when are you accessing the array? The code by itself is technically working fine. `parseInt` is meant to parse integers from strings, it makes no sense to call it on a number type.

Answer (score 0):

I just pasted your code into a JavaScript console and then ran this sequence:

```
> bw = new bandwidth(9600, 0.8, 0.9)
bandwidth
> bw.calcWeightedBandwidth(9600)
7344
> est_bandwidth
[7.171875]
```

So the code seems to run fine and I can access `est_bandwidth` without problems.

Are you executing the script differently?

Comment: in theory...no. I took this sample code (http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/js/dashtest-ibmff.html?MPD=http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/js/content/bunny_ibmff_720.mpd) and I added the declaration of est_bandwidth and the push of the value. Can you have a look?

Comment: As it currently is, I can access your `est_bandwidth` variable just fine using the code you pasted above. If your problem description above is incomplete, update that description please. Or better yet: set up a jsFiddle that reproduces your problem.

Comment: here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/4DY5C/1/ you must refer to banda_stimata instead of est_bandwidth. the code is in bandwidth.js among the sources.